# in Propel pagination: query vs. criteria

Tags: php, zend-framework, orm, propel

I have this query in propel

```
$units = UnitQuery::create()->find();
```

I'm trying to paginate the results returned, so I guess I need to use PropelPager, which according to documentation is created like this

```
$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->add(BookPeer::AUTHOR, $authorId);
$pager = new PropelPager($criteria, 'BookPeer', 'doSelect', $page = 1, $rowsPerPage = 30);
```

What I don't understand is how to convert the 1 line `$units` query that I usually use, to `$criteria`.

Also, is there a way to use a normal query like `$units` with the `PropelPager`? It would be easier than changing the query to use `$criteria` and `doSelect`, etc.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply do this :

```
$units = UnitQuery::create()
    ->filterByStuff($stuff)
    ->paginate($page = 1, $rowsPerPage = 30);
```

And if you really want to use a custom pager (but you probably don't) :

```
$query = UnitQuery::create()->filterByStuff($stuff);
$pager = new MyModelPager($query, $rowsPerPage = 30);
$pager->setPage($page = 1);
$pager->init();
```

Btw, Propel XXXQuery classes are just Criteria on steroids ;)

Answer (score 1):

The pager created by the paginate method is an instance of PropelModelPager which is an entirely different class (conforming to a different interface) to the PropelPager.

As the Query object extends Criteria it is also possible to use the PropelPager which I found necessary as we use a child class of PropelPager which adds caching amongst other things.

> > $unitQuery = UnitQuery::create();
> >
> > $pager = new PropelPager($unitQuery, 'UnitPeer', 'doSelect', $page = 1, $rowsPerPage = 30);